# Translate Excel array formula to VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a calendar with different events.
For that I have the following formula to lookup multiple hits with multiple conditions:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Returnarray, SMALL(IF(Value1 & Value2=Lookuparray1&Lookuparray2, ROW(Returnarray)-MIN(ROW(Returnarray))+1,""), ROW()-Offset)),""))`

I would like to translate this formula to a VBA function, but I can't get it to work.
I tried with `Evaluate` and with `appication.worksheetfunction` but no success.

```
Function MultipleLookup(Offset As Integer, ReturnArray As Range, Value1 As Range, Lookuparray1, Value2 As Range, Lookuparray2 As Range)
    MultipleLookup = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Returnarray, SMALL(IF(Value1 & Value2=Lookuparray1&Lookuparray2, ROW(Returnarray)-MIN(ROW(Returnarray))+1,""), ROW()-Offset)),""))")
End Function
```

I also tried to change the formula and use match instead of if but then it only gives me the first match.

Can somebody please help me to make it work? 
Would it be possible to have a function with a variable amount of criteria?

Thank you

Comment: Are you inserting this into a cell? Or straight through the vba?

Comment: I believe you are complicating things. Start with a part of the code and expand it in small steps.. You are eager to just push a button to make everything happen. Sorry.

Comment: The formula works if I enter it into a cell. I just want to simplify the whole formula becasue I'm using it a lot and it gets a bit messy if there is other things in the same cell.
What I would like is a custom user function that summarizes the bigger one

Comment: You have to double quotation marks inside a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Evaluate` function is one entire string right now and it doesn't use the variables. Try something like this:

```
MultipleLookup = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(" & Returnarray.Address & ", SMALL(IF(" & Value1.Address & " & " & Value2.Address & "=" & Lookuparray1.Address & "&" & Lookuparray2.Address & ", ROW(" & Returnarray.Address & ")-MIN(ROW(" & Returnarray.Address & "))+1,""), ROW()-" & Offset & ")),""))")
```

Comment: unfortunately that does not work. I get a #VALUE error. I think it's because it's an array formula.
Maybe there is a completely different way to achieve the same outcome. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: For array formulas this sort of thing seems to work where you don't use quotes: `Evaluate([MAX(IF(A1:A10=1,ROW(A1:A10),0))])`, but I'm not sure how you would translate that in your case. Otherwise I suggest to use a loop for the "Array" bit of your function to calculate that separately and pass the result of that in the function.

Comment: Does anyone else have an idea ?

Comment: Have you tried creating a loop in VBA to calculate the "Array" bit? Which is everything in the IF-statement I believe?